# Quick Modular Property Help

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is this property always true?

> if $x \mod y = z$, then $ax \mod ay = az$?

for all intergers $x,y,z,a$.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Is "mod" an operator, so $\ x\ {\rm mod}\ y\ $ denotes the remainder, or is "mod" a relation, denoting congruence, i.e. $\,x\equiv y\pmod z \iff z\mid x-y\ ?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $x \equiv z \pmod y \implies x = yk+z$. Then $ax = ayk+za$ and the conclusion follows.

Comment: It's not true if mod denotes a operator (as written).